# RegExp and special characters

Tags: regex, special-characters

I need to use regexp for matching and the code below works fine.  However, I need to KEEP the dollar sign ($) as a true dollar sign and not a special character.

I've tried excluding but nothing is working.

```
IE:  [^$]
```

Here's the code.  It works as expected except when the text contains a $ or IS the $.

```
textNode = "$19,000"; 
regex = RegExp("$19,000",'ig');
text = '$';

textReplacerFunc: function (textNode, regex, text) {
        var sTag = '<span class="highlight">';
        var eTag = '</span>';
        var re = '(?![^<>]*>)(' + text + '(?!#8212;))';
        var regExp = new RegExp(re, 'ig');
        textNode.data = textNode.data.replace(regExp, sTag + '$1' + eTag);
    },
```

RESULT:  $ not highlighted.  desired results:
    $19,000

Comment: Doesn't a backslash make the dollar "not special"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure to double escape the `$` as in :

```
text = '\\$';
```

Since you are using construction of `RegExp` instance using a string here.

Comment: in the string var re, can you please give me an example?  for instance: var re = '(?![^<>]*>)(' + text + '(?!#8212;))';   Where would this be placed?

Comment: Your re string will be: `"(?![^<>]*>)(\$(?!#8212;))"`

Comment: What I showed was `console.log` output but as my answer says a string needs to double escape the `$` for using it in `RegExp` constructor.

Comment: ALMOST THERE!!!!  Thanks.  The string didn't work but what I found by playing around with it did.   If I first replaced the value to be sent as the variable to RegExp with \\$, then it worked fine.  IE  text = '$19,000'.  So text = text.replace('$','\\$') - then use regexp.  Everything worked great.  Thank you so much for getting me started in the right direction!